# How can Install tm Package n R 3.0.3?

Tags: r

I have tried but it gives me error

```
      install.packages("tm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
      Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PAK/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
           Warning in install.packages :
       package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

i want to implement unigram model so that i need methods for words frequency calculation and total number of words counting.
i have a text file as input and i want to implement unigram model for words of whole file.
if you can recommend any thing good instead of tm package?

Comment: Update your R base to the newest version. 3.2.3 and then use it.

Comment: You can navigate through the sea of dependencies by installing everything from source. Or upgrade R.